# Can not read file on NTFS volume although rights are sufficient

Tags: permissions, ntfs

Altough permissions should be OK, one single file on an NTFS partition can not be read, even as root. Not even the 'file' command works.
Any ideas?

```
# file myfile.jpg 
myfile.jpg: ERROR: cannot read `myfile.jpg' (Permission denied)

# whoami
root

# ls -l myfile.jpg 
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 84270 Jul 22  2015 myfile.jpg

# getfacl myfile.jpg 
# file: myfile.jpg
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

# stat myfile.jpg 
  File: »myfile.jpg“
  Size: 84270       Blocks: 168        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 814h/2068d  Inode: 178967      Links: 2
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 0/  root)   Gid: ( 0/  root)
Access: 2010-06-15 20:05:00.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2015-07-22 11:27:48.699794900 +0200
Change: 2015-07-22 11:27:48.699794900 +0200
 Birth: -

# pwd
/mnt/data/foo

# mount | grep data
/dev/sdb4 on /mnt/data type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

# grep data /etc/fstab
UUID=44B45957B4591D2A   /mnt/data              ntfs-3g auto,permissions,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000
```

Answer (score -1):

ok, 5 years too late but the search still reveals this topic:
Issue in my setup an existing file created by Windows and file level encryption on.

```
> $ umount ...
> $ntfsinfo /dev/sde1 -i 3237774
> ...
> Dumping attribute $STANDARD_INFORMATION (0x10) from mft record 3237774(0x31678e)
> ...
>       File attributes: ARCHIVE NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED ENCRYPTED (0x00006020)
```

Comment: Is this a related _question_ or a solution to the question at the top?